# Usar variável em Parameters

Tags: c#

Estou tentando executar a linha abaixo, porem preciso usar variáveis. A linha é a seguinte:

```
CM.Parameters.Add("desnome", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = USU.xdes_nome;
```

Preciso o seguinte: 
`desnome` por variável `Varchar` por variável 
`USU.xdes_nome` por variável

Alguem tem uma dica de como posso fazer?

Comment: poste o contexto onde está esse código, e não entendi `"desnome" por variavel Varchar por variavel USU.xdes_nome por variavel`

Comment: Acho que você entendeu errado o uso do `Parameters.Add`, você não tem que passar o tipo, só o valor.

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta é totalmente vaga, mas tente o seguinte:

```
    CM.Parameters.Add("@desnome", SqlDbType.Int);
    CM.Parameters["@desnome"].Value = USU.xdes_nome;
```

para que o exemplo acima funcione, você precisa checar o "Usu.xdes_nome", se está se referindo a uma variavel sendo chamada de alguma classe, está correto, se não, modifique o nome.